# Visual studio : unsupported URL protocol

Tags: git, visual-studio

I'm having an issue with my git repository in visual studio (2013), when I try to publish a branch. it says "unsupported URL protocol", the url being :

[image]

I can publish the branch correctly in my computer, however it doesn't work on my intern's computer, despite using the exact same git config file in the project :

[image]

the remote repository config is like this :

[image]

Researches I made told me that it might be a TLS 1.2 problem, but even enabling it in VS command prompt doesn't fix the issue, forcing to SSH, HTTPS or HTTP protocol won't fix it either, according full access on the repository doesn't help too.

What could I do to fix that ?

EDIT : when I try to pull directly from a third party git client, it says that my repository isn't a git repository (despite being one), and that it might have to be becasue of right access (it's not, I added my intern to domain admins so he can access everything)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it was a permission problem finally, but either GIT and visual studio was clear about that when trying to PULL, in Visual Studio, it was an unsupported URL error, with GIT client too and suggested that it was a permission problem (but without saying that it's one directly, which is odd).

Comment: so, how can we solve this permission error?